# How to make jquery a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to make a variable out of jquery? I have the following code but it is not working.

```
var container = $('#container');

if(container.is(':visible') == false) $(body).append('<div id="container"></div>'); // I console.log the result and it gives me false

container.append('<p>Test</p>'); // This doesn't append
```

Comment: try like this $a = $('.selector');

Comment: @Scottie no he doesn't, because `container` holds a jQuery collection (albeit empty in this case).

Comment: @ZetCoby: The variable name is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that the selector is computed only when you create the object, so that `container` is still an empty collection when you do the last append.

You should reassign the variable :

```
var container = $('#container');

if(container.is(':visible') == false) {
    $(body).append('<div id="container"></div>');
    container = $('#container');
}

container.append('<p>Test</p>');
```

But if you don't do more, there's no reason to cache `$('#container')`, it's fast to compute.

Comment: `container = $('<div id="container">').appendTo('body');`

Comment: The `if` condition will always be true in this case, right ?

Comment: @Popnoodles What if the container already exists? This will append another `<div id="container">` element to the page?

Comment: I just showed a shorter way to write those two lines.

Comment: @Popnoodles I tried the code and it works. It also checks if the container exists or not. If it exists, it wont append again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to update the variable when you do the append.

You may be better to assess the length of the jQuery collection and then assign a variable accordingly:

```
var $container = $('#container');

if( !$container.length )
{
    $container = $('<div id="container" />');
    $container.appendTo('body');
}

$container.append('<p>Test</p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

`container` might not exist when you try to append something to it.

When you do

```
var container = $('#container');
```

This does not mean that container will always point at any item that has the container id. Rather, it looks for such container, and if it doesn't exist, your container variable is "empty", even if you create a div like that later.

What you want to do is first create the container, and then create the variable, or reassign the correct object to the variable.

Bonus tip, developer usually prefix variables with `$` whenever they are jQuery objects, so that they remember that they don't have to wrap them anymore with `$()`.